# Using Array.getInt(Object array, int index) vs Array[]

Tags: java, arrays

I'm trying to retrieve the item at the specified index in an array as shown in the body of the forloop.

```
public int arrayCount9(int[] nums) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i ++) {
        if (Array.get(nums, i) == 9) {
            count ++;
        }
    }    
    return count;
}
```

However, the correct code in this problem is actually this:

```
public int arrayCount9(int[] nums) {
    int count = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < nums.length; i ++) {
        if (nums[i] == 9) {
            count ++;
        }
    }
    return count;
}
```

Is there a difference between Array.get(nums, i) == 9) and (nums[i] == 9)? The documentation for get(Object array,int index) seems suitable for this problem. In addition, I've actually never encountered (nums[i] == 9) before so if you could explain that code as well, much appreciated!

Comment: I didn't even know this class [`Array`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Array.html) exists. What the heck is the purpose of it?

Comment: @akuzminykh To dynamically create arrays from `Class` objects? I have to agree that most of the methods seem useless

Comment: The `get` method works with arrays of `Object`s.  Use `getInt` instead if you have to. However, I don't understand why you simply can't use the second approach with `nums[i]`

Comment: I will use the second approach as it's the only one working. Just wanted to know the difference between the two. Thanks for your help guys!

Comment: `Array` is the class you'd use when working with the Reflection API and don't want to cast.

Comment: @HarderDatty - You need to replace `Array.get(nums, i) == 9` with `Array.get(nums, i).equals(9)` in order for the first approach to work.

Answer (score 2):

As far as I can tell from [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/reflect/Array.html#get(java.lang.Object,int)), the most important difference between the two is that `Array.get(myArray, myIndex)` will return a raw `Object`, whereas `myArray[myIndex]` will return a value of the type that `myArray` stores.

For example, if you have an array of Strings named `myStringArray`, `Array.get(myStringArray, 4)` will give you a nondescript `Object` value, whereas `myStringArray[4]` will give you a `String` value.

In general, people tend to use the `myArray[myIndex]` syntax unless they have a compelling reason not to. It essentially means "get the item in the array named `myArray` at index `myIndex`."

Comment: Relatively new to java so unsure what's the conventions are but  I'll be using myArray[myIndex] from now on. It seems more intuitive anyways.  thanks a bunch EKW.